# how to understand a manufacturing process w/ uncertain delays & rerouting?

Tags: optimization, operations-research, network-flow

Can anyone tell me what branch of mathematics I need to study in order to better understand the factors that govern the completion times in a multi-step process, in which the thing that's traveling through the process—a product that's being built, let's say—may experience multiple delays or shortcuts of uncertain times, but estimable in type and frequency?

Let's say a team is to revise a book manuscript. The workers include copy and content editors, graphic artists, layout specialists, typographers, printers, binders, and so forth. The manuscript may go from one editor to the graphic artist to the typographer, but then back to the editor who must revise the text because of the new graphics, and then forward again through the chain, but is delayed at some points because a worker doesn't know what to do in a situation, or is continually being interrupted by another process that may also have to do with the book.

How can I begin to model something like this, including travel times and delays in a way that will reveal the weaknesses in the process, identify the culprits, and quantify the potential improvements if certain things are changed in the network or procedure?

Comment: Your question is very broad. You may start looking for stochastic scheduling or stochastic assembly line balancing models.

Comment: Thank you, I will. Queuing theory seems to go in something of this direction, too.

Comment: Assuming that you can quantify things like editorial revision, worker confusion and frequency/duration of interruptions, you could develop a discrete event simulation model (which does not require a lot of study, beyond the ability to come up with relevant probability distributions). Then you can introduce tweaks into the simulation (reduction of distractions, worker training, ...) to see how average performance changes. There's a ton of relatively easy to use simulation software (both free and commercial) out there.

Comment: I've started to do something along those lines—classifying incoming jobs as "long" or "short" according to the estimated time needed to complete them; assigning relative frequencies to the two jobs; and classifying "interruptions" as occurring randomly in time but with their own frequency; and noting the probability that an interruption will stall a long job or a short one. Now, in order to gauge the effect on one's bottom line of such interruptions, equipment failures, or inefficient scheduling, one has to formulate a notion of the cost of delay, or the messiness of a work place.